# Dynamic link based on URL

Tags: php, url, dynamic

#### If someone access my website with this URL:

> https://mywebsite.com/product-page

My link should be like this:

```
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/cart.php?a=add&bid=1">Buy</a>
```

#### And if someone access my website with this other URL:

> https://mywebsite.com/product-page&aff=002

Then my link would change, like this:

```
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/cart.php?a=add&bid=1&aff=002">Buy</a>
```

### 'Been messing with some codes but still no luck, does anyone knows how to do this?

## Thanks!

Comment: like this https://mywebsite.com/product-page&aff=002 or https://mywebsite.com/product-page?aff=002 ?

Comment: Sorry, it's https://mywebsite.com/aff.php?aff=002&bid=1

Comment: Do you need it for many $_GET variables, or just for the `aff=*` variable?

Comment: Just the aff, but @Jack nailed it. Thanks for your time guys!

Comment: There's just one issue, it's in the comments bellow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a decorating function for it:

```
function getTrackingLink($url)
{
    if (isset($_GET['aff'])) {
        $url .= (strrpos($url, '?') === false ? '?' : '&') . 'aff=' . urlencode($_GET['aff']);
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Then:

```
<a href="<?php echo getTrackingLink('/cart.php?a=add&bid=1'); ?>">Buy</a>
```

Comment: Just one thing, it is outputing like this: example.com/aff.php&bid=1?aff=002, it should be like this: example.com/aff.php?aff=002&bid=1, here's the code: href="<?php echo getTrackingLink('/painel/aff.php&bid=1'); ?>"